# ?Why is my CSS not applying?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my CSS is not applying to my HTML.

HTML:

```
<textarea class="overlay-display-hide preview-caption" placeholder="Add Your Caption here..."></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay-display-hide {
    display: hide !important;
}
.preview-caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 360px;
    height: 260px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-style: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And for some reason, the "overlay-display-hide" class does not show up in the element when inspecting. Do you have any ideas? I bet I just oversaw something.

Comment: Your DOM might not  loaded, util it not get loaded your css will not work

Comment: Why here is display: hide !important; display hide is not a valid value it should be block or none

Comment: Well, it works to me, what's the problem ? Are you sure you've correctly saved the HTML document ?

Comment: your `overlay-display-hide` is useless here.

Answer (score 3):

Does not exist `display: hide`. Read all properties from this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

For example, if you want to hide element use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`

```
.overlay-display-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually does render correctly, and I can also see the class in the Chrome inspector. But the browser will ignore your property of `display: hide` because it is the wrong syntax. You can [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display), what values are supported, but `hide` is none of them.

I assume you are looking for `display: none`. You can see the element in DOM Tree of the inspector of your browser, but it will not be applied to the page.
The other option is `visibility: hidden`, which will just dont display the element, but it acutally takes the space in the page, so it is there, but not visible.

See the following example to understand the difference between `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`

```css
.col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.elem {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <h1>visibility: hidden</h1>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem hidden"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <h1>display: none</h1>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem none"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use `display: none` instead of `display: hide` to hide something. You can explore more on the `display` property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

There are other ways to hide HTML elements that `display: none` might not be appropriate for, follow this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-ways-to-hide-elements-in-css/) for that.

What are your intentions though? It's not so clear.